# Convert CFString into Python string

Tags: python, core-foundation

I have a CFString and would like to use it in Python.

What is the fastest way to do so? Is it possible to avoid the conversion, i.e. to somehow create Python string just from the CFString pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to avoid the conversion, i.e. to somehow create Python string just from the CFString pointer?

Not that I know of. Python is made to be cross-platform, and there's not really any reason for it to use CFStrings internally even when they are available.

You *may* be able to get the string's backing [C string](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFStringGetCStringPtr), [MacRoman Pascal string](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFStringGetPascalStringPtr), or [UTF-16 character buffer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFStringGetCharactersPtr), but every one of these is allowed to fail, so you cannot rely on any of them working. You must always implement copying the characters to your own buffer as the last attempt.

You probably should not even try the Pascal-string route, since you'd still need to convert from MacRoman to UTF-8. You might as well just use the string's own conversion API at that point.

> What is the fastest way to [convert]?

If any of the above shortcuts (aside from the Pascal-string one) succeeds, it will be the fastest way.

One way or another, you need to get a buffer containing the characters in some form, then create a Python string from that buffer.

It's worth mentioning at this point that in Python 2.x, the `str` type is a pure 8-bit-data object. For this reason, Python 3 renamed it to `bytes`, and you should consider it the Python counterpart to NS/CFData, not NS/CFString.

NS/CFStrings contain Unicode characters, so you want [Python's `unicode` (`str` in Python 3) type](http://docs.python.org/c-api/unicode.html).

Beware of `CFStringGetLength`: It returns the length in UTF-16 code units. If you end up using UTF-8, the length in UTF-8 code units may be different.

From that Python documentation, here's how you'd create a Python string, depending on what you're able to get from the CFString:

- [The `PyUnicode_FromString` function](http://docs.python.org/c-api/unicode.html#PyUnicode_FromString) takes a UTF-8-encoded C string.
- [The `PyUnicode_FromStringAndSize` function](http://docs.python.org/c-api/unicode.html#PyUnicode_FromStringAndSize) takes a buffer of UTF-8-encoded characters, and the size of that buffer. This is probably faster than `FromString`.
- [The `PyUnicode_FromUnicode` function](http://docs.python.org/c-api/unicode.html#PyUnicode_FromUnicode) takes a buffer of UTF-16-encoded characters, and the size of that buffer.

#### TL;DR

Use Python's `unicode` (PyUnicode) class only; not `str`/`bytes`/`PyString`/`PyBytes`.

I'd try `GetCStringPtr` (requesting UTF-8) first. If it succeeds, I'd call `CFStringGetMaximumSizeForEncoding` to determine (hopefully more quickly than `strlen`) the length of that string, and then call `PyUnicode_FromStringAndSize` to create the Python string.

Next, I'd ask the CFString [what's the fastest encoding to convert it to](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFStringGetFastestEncoding).

- If the fastest encoding is UTF-16 (or, as CFString calls it, “Unicode”), I'd use `CFStringGetLength`, `CFStringGetCharactersPtr`, `CFStringGetCharacters` (if `GetCharactersPtr` fails), and `PyUnicode_FromUnicode`.
- Otherwise, I'd use [the `CFStringGetBytes` function](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFStringGetBytes) once to determine the buffer size needed for conversion to UTF-8, then again to perform that conversion, then `PyUnicode_FromStringAndSize`.

(I should point out that that “if” may be premature optimization. `CFStringGetBytes` is CFString's central text-encoding-conversion function; it is capable of returning *any* encoding, including UTF-16. You may want to write both the conditional `CFStringGetCharacters{Ptr,}` solution and the unconditional `CFStringGetBytes` solution and time them against each other, as well as see whether the fastest encoding ever actually is UTF-16 for the strings you're currently handling.)

Comment: Thank you for such a complex answer. I'm unable to obtain the fast pointers so I guess I will have to do some conversion. Thanks once more!

Answer (score -2):

why do you wanna use a CFString in python.. BTW CF string has its own structure defined and the way it was stored in memory is different than python string. Its not possible to do this conversion.

Comment: If you can access the characters from the CFString in the right order, you can create a corresponding python string.